# The way of concatenating similar name variables

Tags: python

Using python, I want to make the following 'tests' list.
'tests = [1,2,3]' that I want to get 
I know the bellow works, 
`tests = [test1, test2, test3]`

How can I make tests easily, using for loop? 
I wrote like bellow, but it results in 'tests = [test1, test2, test3]'

```
test1 = [1]
test2 = [2]
test3 = [3]
tests = []
for i in raange(3):
    test.append('test'+str(i))
```

Comment: `tests = [test1, test2, test3]`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: @Ell Thanks I know that, but I wanted to know the different way

Answer (score -1):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
tests = [eval("test%d" % (i+1)) for i in range(3)]
```

Output:

```
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

Comment: what's the alternative? :)

Comment: OP should not use variables like `test1`, `test2` ... in the first place, but list of lists... otherwise you can look the variables up in `locals()` or `globals()` dict

Answer (score -4):

```
test1 = [1]
test2 = [2]
test3 = [3]
tests = []
for i in range(3):
    tests.append("test"+str(i))
```

will work

Comment: This appends strings, not lists, to tests.

Comment: Yes, but in question there is nothing about content of tests list. Author didn't say that this must be list of list, or list of elements, that came from test1, test2 and test3

Comment: @darvark Sorry, my question is not appropriate. I changed the question. It was my first time to post a question. From now, I will be careful when posting.